# How to remove url from friendlyID slug if user inputs www.examplesite.com/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am letting users enter a custom url slug in their profile page on sign up. When someone inevitably puts https://www.examplesite.com/exampleSlug || www.examplesite.com/exampleSlug etc in the form field as well as the slug itself. Instead of just example site.

Is there a handy way in rails to remove all of the matches for the urls?

```rb
def slug_filter
    if self.slug[/\Ahttps:\/\/www.examplesite.com\//] || self.slug[/\Ahttp:\/\/www.examplesite.com\//] || self.slug[/\Awww.examplesite.com\//] || self.slug[/\Aexamplesite.com\//]
# Not sure what to do here?
      self.slug = self.slug
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.slug = slug.sub /.*\//, ''`

Comment: In my model.rb
```
after_save: slug 

def slug=(value)
    write_attribute(:slug, value.gsub(/.*\//, ''))
  end
```